Spring Tool Suite executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library
I have downloaded Spring Tool Suite (STS) and unzipped the file. After that I am trying to run application it is showing:
"STS executable launcher was unable to locate it's companion shared library"
I have uninstalled and installed twice but it is showing same propblem.

Maybe a problem with permissions on the file system, maybe the unzipping caused a problem, ight be various reasons why this fails that way. Best way to track this down would be to double check the content of the SpringToolSuite4.ini file, look for the location of the launcher library setting and check the existence of that file - as a starting point.
